# Angular 2 - Toggle directive component depending on page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular, angular2-directives

Lets say I have *Home*, *About* and *Advanced Search* pages. In my `AppComponent` html I have this:

```
<view-header></view-header>
<view-search></view-search>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<view-footer></view-footer>
```

Quite simple. First I load my header's html, and then my default search's html and then on and on.

As I said earlier, I have the page *Search*. Obviously, I don't want to show my directive `view-search` because it's pretty useless when you're in the *Advanced Search* page.

So my question is, How can I tell Angular2 to disable the view-search directive when I route to my *Advanced Search* page?

---

*Edit 1*

In other words, I want to do something like that:

```
<view-header></view-header>

<!-- If (not in route "/search") -->
    <view-search></view-search>
<!-- Endif -->

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<view-footer></view-footer>
```

Comment: Use `route.subscribe` to check for current active route maybe

Comment: @AngJobs Thank you for your reply, never heard of it. I'll check it out.

Comment: No probs, it's in official docs https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how the `route.param.subscribe` does answer my question.

Comment: Have you tried then `this.router.routerState.root` it should show you the Activatedroute

Comment: @AngJobs I'm really sorry but I don't understand how is it related to my question.

Comment: I think your Search component could hide itself if `this.router.routerState.root=="Advanced Search"`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `ngIf` (or bind to `[hidden]`) in your template:

```
<view-header></view-header>
<view-search *ngIf="showViewSearch"></view-search>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<view-footer></view-footer>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Where you would define `showViewSearch` as

```
constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
  this.showViewSearch = activatedRoute.component !== Search
}
```

So `viewSearch` component is rendered only if current route is not Search.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I tried to do as u mentioned, but I didn't find in my whole project the class `ActivatedRoute`. Maybe it's in a different version? my version is - `angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.2-mobile.4`

Comment: What version of the router you are using? ActivatedRoute is exported by `@angular/route` of version 3.x.

Comment: "@angular/router": "2.0.0-rc.1". Should I upgrade it to 3.x?

Comment: Yes, v2 router is deprecated and v3 is going to be released with stable v1 of Angular 2. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html